# InternetGetCookie does not retrieve all cookies

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I am trying to use InternetGetCookie in order to retrieve cookies from IE. The problem I have is that sometimes in a cookie file there may be 2 or even 3 different cookies but InternetGetCookie always retrieves the data associated with only the first cookie.  I tried calling InternetGetCookie twice in a row for the same cookie url but it all it does is two retrieve the first cookie data twice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where (what process) is your code running in? What do you mean when you when you say "same cookie url"?

Some notes:

- InternetGetCookie will not return HTTPOnly cookies by default
- InternetGetCookie will return only persistent cookies and session cookies from the *current* process. It does not see session cookies from other processes.
- On Vista+, InternetGetCookie will not return cookies from Protected Mode processes

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx

Answer (score 0):

InternetGetCookie returns all cookies separated by ';' symbol.

Comment: I am afraid id does not: I have tested InternetGetCookie and it only retrieves the first cookie.

Answer (score 0):

It does not return `HttpOnly` marked cookie. See if your second cookie is `HttpOnly` marked. If it is so then use `InternetGetCookieEx()` with `INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` Flag.