# reading cookies in IE addon

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I am writing an IE addon . I need to enumerate and read cookies. I know how to get the cookies of the current page but thats not what I want; i need to see all cookies including session cookies

I know they are in files somewhere but I need session cookies; similarly there is an InternetGetCookie api, but that only gets persistent cookies

Comment: possible duplicate of [InternetGetCookie does not retrieve all cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559777/internetgetcookie-does-not-retrieve-all-cookies)

Answer (score 0):

InternetGetCookieEx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

.............

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: the essential part of the answer is the name of the API call, the link is provided as a convenience (and also because SO doesn't allow such a short answer)

Comment: The function obtains a cookie for a given Url, but it does not enumerate all cookies in the browser cache. So it is only a partial answer to the question.